# VBA to remove duplicate rows in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Using the code below, I open a workbook, I then need to remove all duplicate from the rows in the opened workbook (nb).

```
Dim nb As Workbook, tw As Workbook, ts As Worksheet
 a = Application.GetOpenFilename
 If a = False Or IsEmpty(a) Then Exit Sub
 With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Set tw = ThisWorkbook
Set ts = tw.ActiveSheet
Set nb = Workbooks.Open(a)
```

I have tried various methods of getting this to work, but it appears I lack a fundamental part in order to call this on the workbook. I get an 424 Object Required error.

```
'Remove duplicates
Dim r As Range
c = nb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LR = c - 1

Set r = nb.ActiveSheet.Range("A8:H" & LR)
r.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

The line that is given the error(424 Object required), is

```
r.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

I think it is because r is a range, but not set to the specific workbook,

When I look at the object r, it is sheet to the Sheet in the wrong workbook. I am not understanding why, because I explicitly  mark r as being the external workbook here

```
    Set r = nb.ActiveSheet.Range("A8:H" & LR)
```

Comment: You assigned `LR` two values and I presume `LR = -1` needs to be `LR = LR - 1`? Because now `LR = -1` and `H-1` is no valid cell.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that. LR is not set as the number of rows -1, because the last row is a Totals row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a merged cell, when there are merged cells in the range that has duplicates the VBA code does not know what to do, as far as I can figure out.

Following is a sub for opening an external workbook, and removed dublicates in a range, from worksheet 1

```
Sub remDup3()
Dim nb As Workbook, tw As Workbook, ts As Worksheet
 a = Application.GetOpenFilename
 If a = False Or IsEmpty(a) Then Exit Sub
 With Application
 .ScreenUpdating = False
 End With
 Set tw = ThisWorkbook
 Set ts = tw.ActiveSheet
 Set nb = Workbooks.Open(a)

LR = nb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

        With nb.Sheets(1)
        Set Rng = Range("A9:H" & LR)
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4), Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Activesheet` -> it hurts my eyes.

Name your sheet, then call them with

```
LR = nb.sheets('somesheet').Range("A1:H" & LR)
```

You'll notice less bugs in your program overall. 
Try to explicitly activate the workbook and sheet before setting the range.

**Edit** 
Based on your second problem, you should debug:

1) Check the used range

```
Dim oRange as excel.range 

nb.sheets("NAMEYOURSHEET").activate 
set oRange = nb.sheets("NAMEYOURSHEET").UsedRange
```

In the immediate window type: `oRange.select`  + 'Enter key'.
If you get a bug somewhere here, then you know where your problem lies.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but changing to `LR = nb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H" & LR)` does not remove the error. Which it won't do, because the LR is being used in the same line as it is now being defined.

Comment: Try replacing all the activesheets. Try to explicitly activate the workbook and sheet before setting the range.

Comment: I've updated the code in the post, to show that it is not throwing a 424 object required error, I am guessing it is because VBA doesn't know where to apply the remove duplicates, even though LR has been defined as being the external opened workbook.